# Logout.php doesn't work

Tags: php, logout

```
<?php
     session_start();
     if (!isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])) {
      header("Location: index.php");
     } else if(isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])!="") {
      header("Location: home.php");
     }

     if (isset($_GET['Odjava'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['korisnik']);
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
      header("Location: index.php");
      exit();
     }
     ?>
```

Everytime I press logout, home.php is just refreshed and session is not over.

Comment: Because `else if(isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])!="") ` is true so it opens the `home.php` again and session is not over.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out.
This worked perfectly fine:
<?php
 session_start();
  unset($_SESSION['korisnik']);
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit();
 ?>

Comment: [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns a boolean (true/false) not a string so you need to check for that.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])!="")` is a false positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

 if (isset($_GET['Odjava'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['korisnik']);
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: index.php");
  exit();
 }

 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])) {
  header("Location: index.php");
 } else if(isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])!="") {
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Try this as you need to check it is set first otherwise your script will redirect as your if statement is above the session destroy

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['korisnik'])!="")` that's still a "false positive" and will fail them. It needs to be in two separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

to me this does the trick:

```
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), 1); 
$_SESSION = [];
```

i.e first make the session expire
(after the first second in the year 1970),
then clear the $_SESSION variable.

Answer (score -1):

Your first if block is run first and the session is still set at that time. Reverse the order of your if blocks and you may get a better result.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) approach:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

In order to delete also the session cookies.

Comment: I found this works in the reverse order. First make the session expire, then clear the $_SESSION variable.